# What is the "rice milling commission" on sake?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, food, terminology

I was looking at a bottle of sake I had been given. It had a 60% on it and I wondered what it meant:

> [image]

I ran it through the Google Translate for images - and it gave me this:

> [image]

In regard to the 60% - Google Translate gave me "rice milling commission 60%".

I don't feel any more informed. Do the rice millers get 60% of the profits of the bottle sales?

My question is: **What is the rice milling commission on sake?**

Comment: "Sake dumpling tool"?  "Comission"?  Nowhere on the label does it say those.  Even I, a pure amateur, could do a far better translation than that.

Comment: @l'électeur, I would love it if someone would invent a Japanese sake dumpling tool.  :)

Comment: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/精米歩合 I think you should research more. When searching, you shouldn't use Google Translate. (because there is wrong translations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

精米歩合 refers to the ratio of white rice to the original brown rice. (If you polish 100kg of brown rice until you have 60kg of white rice, then your 精米歩合 is 60%.)

(This has nothing to do with "commission".)

Comment: Really?  I have always thought it was the opposite.  I thought 大吟醸 had the lowest 精米歩合.　The lower the 精米歩合, the more polishing, I thought.

Comment: @l'électeur You're right. I confused it with ぶづき米, where the higher the number, the more polished the rice. (I.e. 7分づき is whiter than 5分づき.)

Comment: Yeah, 精米歩合 is a tricky word.  It is how much of the  rice grains you have left after the polishing, and not how much of the rice you have polished off of the grains.

Answer (score 1):

Its has to do with the 'rice polishing ratio which is one way of categorizing sake:

http://www.nymtc.com/Japanese-Sake/Learning-About-Sake_Rice-Polishing-Ratio.html